# What is extended display format

Tags: c++, directx

MSDN documentation for **[GetAdapterDisplayMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174316(v=vs.85).aspx)** says in remarks the following

> Remarks
>
> GetAdapterDisplayMode will not return the correct format when the
>   display is in an **extended format, such as 2:10:10:10**. Instead, it
>   returns the format X8R8G8B8.

What does it mean by extended format? What is 2:10:10:10? Is it related to some display configuration e.g. extended display, display on remote desktop connection?

Some context:

I am having hard time getting correct `D3DFORMAT`. Setting `d3dPresentParameters.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8` gives correct output in one environment but does not in another.

Both environments are same (Windows 7 64 bit with Nvidia hardware) but I guess some display configuration has changed between them.

Comment: I can't seem to articulate in words what I have in my head. But this might lead you down the path to some answers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn941339(v=vs.85).aspx  I think it's to do with the render capability of one of the environments.

Comment: I would assume it is a special Format with 2 bit Alpha, and 10 bits / each color channel. Just a blind shot: Check driver versions, and the settings within the driver utilities. Newer versions usually come with a suite where several D3D-related settings can be forced. This is definitly a place where such difference in the environments may originate.

Comment: @antipattern Problem randomly starts on any system and stays there. Drivers are the same on all systems. One environment runs fine with `D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8` and the other with `D3DFMT_R5G6B5` I guess first is for 32bit and second is for 16bit. Following [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/DirectX/9.0/Direct3D/Initialization) always returns `D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8` as best or current display mode.